# Magento 2: getting Full Action name inside custom Model class?

Tags: magento2, module, model

Would you please let me know best way to get the Full Action name inside custom Model class in Magento 2?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, your models should not depend on the request. You should find an other way of passing what you need from the request to the model.
But if you insist... you can do this.
Inject an instance of the request in the model constructor, like this:

```
protected $request;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    ...
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Then you can get the full action name like this:

```
$action = $this->request->getFullActionName();
```

Comment: I tried this code in my custom controller contruct method but not work.Any other pattern to create object of  \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http class

Answer (score 1):

**Try not to use Objectmanager. It is just for fast implementation**

> If the url is http://localhost/mage242/customer/account/login

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
echo $request->getRouteName() . '<br />';           //customer
echo $request->getModuleName() . '<br />';          //customer
echo $request->getControllerName() . '<br />';      //account
echo $request->getActionName() . '<br />';          //login
echo $request->getFullActionName() . '<br />';      //customer_account_login
echo $request->getControllerModule() . '<br />';    //Magento_Customer
```

*Vote this answer up if it helps.*

Answer (score 0):

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {
if($request->getControllerName() == 'product' && $request->getModuleName() == 'catalog'){
    $request->setModuleName('cms')->setControllerName('page')->setActionName('view')->setParam('page_id', 8);
}else if($request->getControllerName() == 'category' && $request->getModuleName() == 'catalog'){
    $request->setModuleName('cms')->setControllerName('page')->setActionName('view')->setParam('page_id', 7);
}else{
    $request->setModuleName('cms')->setControllerName('index')->setActionName('index'); 
}
```

it's working in controller

Answer (score -1):

**At Phtml you can use**

> `$block->getRequest()->getFullActionName();`

**BlocK**

> ```
> $this->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
> ```

Comment: pls answer to this question   ............https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319361/magento-2-checkout-move-shipping-methods-block-to-payment-step