# Detect Success Page on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

Is there a way to check if am I on Success page on Magento 2?

I know in Magento 1 we can check and compare the action name, for example. But in Magento 2, there is something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where in the flow you need to detect it, for styling purposes, you can see in the body tag of the success page this css class:
**checkout-onepage-success**

If you need to interact with data in the page you could hook to this event: **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**

And in Magento2 you also have action/module names and handles that you could use in your php/phtml code:

[Magento 2: How to get controller, module, action and router name?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104635/magento-2-how-to-get-controller-module-action-and-router-name/104638)

[Current page layout handle Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51709/current-page-layout-handle-magento2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the same at Magento 2. Get Full action can at your class or file .

[Magento 2: getting Full Action name inside custom Model class?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96107/magento-2-getting-full-action-name-inside-custom-model-class)

```
if( $this->request->getFullActionName() === 'checkout_onepage_success){
// then checkout page
}
```

Comment: Thanx, but I will run my code inside the head tag, so it's not possible go with "$this". There is an alternative, like in Magento 1 we had "Mage::app()"?

Comment: what you want to under `head` tag , if you will inject `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http ` respective  code then you can get full action

Comment: Thank you, Amit :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the code below [here](https://roshanyadav007.wordpress.com/2020/02/14/magento-2-how-to-identify-current-page-in-phtml-file/)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context')->getRequest();


if ($request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_onepage_success') {
//you are on the success page
}
```